# Excel VBA, If "no" is selected in dropdown list then replace with formula

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I have a sheet where R3:R102 contains drop down lists where you can either select “Yes” or leave blank. I want the cell to automatic select “Yes” if cell on the left (Q) contains specific text.

I.e. 
If Q5 = ”High” or “Moderate” then R5 = Yes 
However, if the cell contains text other than “high” or “moderate” for instance “low” I want to be able to select “Yes” in the dropdown list in R5.

The problem I have is that if I select “Yes” in R5 and then change it back to blank, the formula in the cell disappears. If then Q5 changes from “low” to “moderate”, “yes” is no longer automatically selected.

Is there a VBA code to solve this problem?

I am quite new to VBA, so I only know the basics. I would much appreciate all help! Thank you.

Comment: Are the drop down list ComboBox Form control, ComboBox ActiveX control, or Data validation ones?

Comment: Hi, please understand that Stack Overflow is not a "please write the code for me" website. You need to provide what you have so far to help us better understand your problem and we can assist with the code. Have you written any code just far? If so, please post it by editing your post.

Comment: Hi @VincentG
The drop down list is Data validations as they are in every cell from R3:R102.

Comment: Hi @KoderM16
I tried a version with a "help formula" seven cells right.: `For Each c in Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R3:R102") If c.Value <> "Yes" Then c.Value = FormulaR1C1 = [RC7] End If Next c` But this makes the woorkbook very slow.